# I run this comman in terminal: docker-compose up dev-db -d & it gives the following error: services.networks must be a mapping

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Here is docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dev-db:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
      POSTGRES_DB: nest
    networks:
      - freecodecamp
  networks:
    freecodecamp
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. If the question is why the error occurs: it says in the error message: "*services.networks must be a mapping*". For the final `freecodecamp`, It should be `freecodecamp:` instead of only `freecodecamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `networks` definition needs to be pulled out a level, so it lines up with `services`, like this

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dev-db:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
      POSTGRES_DB: nest
    networks:
      - freecodecamp
networks:
  freecodecamp:
```

Like Turing85 says, it also needs a colon after the network name.

Comment: Now it gives the following error:
⠿ dev-db Error                                                                                                 0.0s
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:34623->[::1]:53: read: connection refused